Can’t coding machine learning model with data array 1*10201
I've written code for topology optimization and want to add machine learning using data collected from looping from topology optimization as a dataframe, as in the picture, J_old has one value in each column, but the lamda and sensitivity values ​​are 1*10201 array, sensitivity is output targeted that i want this model to predict
I coding machine learning model with data as show in this picture
data
And, I want x_data to be a data in column 'J_old' and 'lamda' , how could i do it ??
x_data = df['J_old']
y_data = df['sensitivity']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data1, y_data1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = Sequential()

input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 40, 40, 2), name='input_data')  #input size=40
model_dens = model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='softmax')) #units in dense = 64, softmax = output is array
output_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 40, 40, 1), name='output_true') #input size=40
learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [], name='learning_rate')

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae']) 
#model.fit(x=trainX, y=trainY,validation_data=(testX, testY),epochs=200)
#model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
# Print model summary
model.summary()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[160], line 19
     16 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae']) 
     17 #model.fit(x=trainX, y=trainY,validation_data=(testX, testY),epochs=200)
     18 #model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
---> 19 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
     20 # Print model summary
     21 model.summary()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py:81, in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
     79   return bytes_or_text
     80 else:
---> 81   raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
     82                   (bytes_or_text,))

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got array([-0.24753326+0.j, -0.24753326+0.j, -0.2500359 +0.j, ...,
       -0.34861478+0.j, -0.34856497+0.j, -0.34856497+0.j])

and how could i fix this error??
